# How can I get the actual size of a UIVIewController view open modally?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, size

I'm opening a view controller modally and on the ViewDidLoad of the UIViewController that has been opened modally I need to know its width and height.
This became a problem when I tested on a iPad 12.9 inches. UIViewControllers open modally will not occupy the full screen height or width, which if fine, but I need to know the size of this view.

This is the way I am opening a UIViewController modally:

```
viewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Important note: I need to know the size of my UIViewController view on ViewDidLoad. Using self.view.frame or self.view.bounds at this point however will get the size of the full screen, which is not in fact the size the UIViewController view size when the view opens.

Additional info: I am performing this test on iOS15.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the actual height of the ViewController in the viewDidLayoutSubviews method and any additional ui updates should be done here.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
 // Actual height
    NSLog(@"%f",self.view.frame.size.height);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, this does not solve my problem because I need to access the size of this modal UIVIewController view on viewDidLoad. Accessing self.view.frame or self.view.bounds at this point have the width and height of the full screen. I am going to update my question with this additional request.

Comment: May I ask why do you only need it on viewDidLoad?
Unless you set some fixed constraints and/or calculate it, you can't really get the height in viewDidLoad because the constraints haven't applied yet.

Comment: I was populating my UIViewController view on the ViewDidLoad because it runs on the very beginning and only once. It seemed the right event to do it until now. Unfortunately the view.frame / view.bounds are not correct on ViewDidLoad when opening a UIViewController modally. What I did now was to populate the UIViewController view on the ViewWillAppear but only the first time it runs which happens to run before viewDidLayedSubViews which runs more than once.

Comment: You can introduce a value to make sure your function runs only once, like this: 
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
 [super viewWillAppear:animated];
 if (self.shouldLoad) { 
[self yourFunction];
 self.shouldLoad = false; 
}
}

Comment: Yes that was what I ended up doing. Thank you Andrei!